# Expressjs Using object title as dynamic url

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to figure out how to route my GET individual objects route parameter by title as opposed to ID. I know that `body-parser` allows for the request, but can't figure out how to modify my current route setup to allow for this to happen.

My thoughts were to change all blogpost_id to blogpost_title, but I'm running into this error.

```
{
  "message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"Data Cost Upload\" at path \"_id\"",
  "name":"CastError",
  "type":"ObjectId",
  "value":"Data Cost Upload",
  "path":"_id"
}
```

routes.js:

```
//Route for individual blogs
    router.route('/blog/:blogpost_id')


    // START GET method blog by ID  
    .get(function(req, res) {



        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blogpost) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);


            //res.json(blogpost);
            res.render('pages/blogpost', {
                blogpost: blogpost
            });
        });
    }) // END GET method blog by ID

    // START PUT method
    .put(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blogpost) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);


            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // update the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // update the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // update the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // update the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // update the category 
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; //update the tags


            blogpost.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);


                res.json({ message: 'Blog updated.' });
            });

        });

    }) // END PUT method

    // START DELETE method
    .delete(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.remove({
            _id: req.params.blogpost_id

        }, function(err, bear) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        });
    });
```

How I'm linking through to each individual object:

```
<div class="blog-content">
                <% blogpost.forEach(function(blogpost) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h2><a href="#" class="blog-title"><%= blogpost.title %></a></h2></td>
                        <td><h3><%= blogpost.date %></h3></td>
                        <td><h3 class="blog-category"><%= blogpost.category %></h3></td>
                        <td><h3 class="blog-tagline"><i><%= blogpost.tagline %></i></h3></td>
                        <td><p><%=: blogpost.content | truncate:800 | append:'...' %></p></td>
                        <td><a href="/blog/<%= blogpost.title %>" class="blog-read-more">Read More</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
            </div>
```

Result URL from clicking on "Read More": `http://localhost:8080/blog/Data%20Cost%20Upload`

Answer (score 0):

when you get `http://localhost:8080/blog/Data%20Cost%20Upload`

`route.get` handler called with `req.params.blogpost_id = "Data Cost Upload"`.

`Blogs.findById` expects first argument to be `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`, but `req.params.blogpost_id` is a `string`

If you want to get your blogpost by title, use

```
function getSearchCriteria(params) {
      return {
          title: params.blogpost_title
      };
}

function getBlogpostUpdate(body) {
      return {
           title: body.title,
           author: body.author,
           tagline: body.tagline,
           content: body.content,
           category: body.category,
           tags: body.tags
      };
}

var blogpostsRoute = router.route('/blog/:blogpost_title');

// to manipulate your route params, use router.param
router.param('blogpost_title', function (req, res, next, blogpost_title) {
    req.params.blogpost_title = blogpost_title.toLowerCase();
    next();
});

blogpostsRoute 
    .get(function (req, res) {
         var searchCriteria = getSearchCriteria(req.params);
         Blogpost.findOne(searchCriteria, function (err, blogpost) {
             if (err)
                 res.send(err);
             res.render('pages/blogpost', {
                 blogpost: blogpost
             })
         })
     })
     .put(function (req, res) {
         var searchCriteria = getSearchCriteria(req.params);
         var updated = getBlogpostUpdate(req.body)
         Blogpost.findOneAndUpdate(searchCriteria, updated, function (err, updated) {
             if (err)
                 res.send(err);


             res.json({ message: 'Blog updated.' });
         });
     })
     .delete(function (req, res) {
         var searchCriteria = getSearchCriteria(req.params);
         Blogpost.findOneAndRemove(searchCriteria, function (err, removed) {
             if (err)
                res.send(err);

             res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
         });
     });
```

Comment: hey @Andrew Volchenko, thank you for the response. I made your changes but ran into an error with the 
`function getBlogpostUpdate(body)` 
Error:          
`  title = body.title,
                 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)`. Also, why is Blogs used instead of Blogpost. I don't have a model attached to a variable `Blogs`

Comment: hey @cphill, sorry, made stupid mistakes :( Check it now

Comment: this works perfectly. I do have one other question, if I wanted to set the characters in the route to lowercase, would I set the .lowerCase in the router parameter or within one of the functinos?

Comment: Hey @Andrew Volchenko. Thank you! Sorry to bother again, but it appears that it isn't working. I'm getting a long load and then a `no data received` page. Could it be the way i'm linking the view? `<a href="/blog/<%= blogpost.title %>" class="blog-read-more">Read More</a>`

Comment: @cphill, yes, sorry, my bad. I've forgot to call `next()` in `route.param`. But even after this change you'll get empty responce, because when you'll try to get `http://localhost:port/blog/My%20Awesome%20BlogPost`, route.param will change 'My Awesome BlogPost' to 'my awesome blogpost' but there is no blogpost with title 'my awesome blogpost' :) So, you need to add additional field in your blogpost documents (e.g. blogpost.name), that would be title in lowercase, and change searchCriteria from {title: 'smth'}, to {name: 'smth'}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62509/discussion-between-andrew-volchenko-and-cphill).